# Why does this Grails download behave strangely?

Tags: grails, groovy, amazon-s3

I've written a Grails application that connects to S3 and streams a file back to the client. This has worked great so far, up until I've tried to use it to download a large (2GB) file. I see the following behaviour:

- When starting the download normally by calling the controller, after around 1GB, the download 'completes'.
- Opening multiple tabs to trigger several simultaneous downloads causes the downloads to 'complete' after a few MB, although the actual amount downloaded seems to be random each time. This can also be observed when performing simultaneous downloads on multiple machines.

In both cases, the error messages are the same:

```
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver SocketException occurred when processing request: [GET] /download
Connection reset.:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

errors.GrailsExceptionResolver IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /download
getOutputStream() has already been called for this response.
```

Here's the part of the controller concerned with the download:

**DownloadController.groovy**

```
def index() {
    def fileStream = s3Service.getStream()
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=foo.csv")
    response.contentType = "text/csv"
    response.outputStream = fileStream
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

..and a snippet of the service that connects to S3 and gets the file:

**S3Service.groovy**

```
def getStream() {
    def outputStream = ""
    try {
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client()
        S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest('my-bucket-name', 'path/to/file.csv'))
        outputStream = object.getObjectContent()
    }
    catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        /* Log the error. Omitted for brevity. */
    }
    catch (AmazonClientException ase) {
        /* Log the error. Omitted for brevity. */
    }
    return outputStream
}
```

I'm really stumped as to what's causing this.

Comment: Have you tried taking s3 out of the picture and see if you can recreate the issue with a local file? Also, what version of Grails are you using? In addition what happens if you use org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy to copy the file stream to the response output stream (which is highly optimized)? Lastly, `response.outputStream.close()` is also a good idea (expresses intent).

Comment: It turns out it wasn't Grails' fault after all - see my answer below. Thanks for your comment though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this error was occurring because the app is running on a server behind a load balancer, which is attempting to cache files that pass through it. It's unable to cache the larger files as it has limited disk space, and the download fails.

This was verified by connecting an instance of the app running locally to AWS, and observing that the strange behaviour no longer occurs.